# Do I need to restart startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges after every new location update?

Tags: iphone, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I start startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges when my app goes into the background, I make sure that when didUpdateToLocation is triggered, it will check for cached location and invalid accuracy readings and then return from the method. But if I do get a good location update, do I need to restart startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges by adding:

```
[manager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
[manager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
```

At the end?
I want the app to keep monitoring for significant changes when it is in the background.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It'll will keep updating until you call `stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`.